# Is there a safe way to automatically remove a stray unix-socket files before it’s related services are run?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, systemd, supervisord

I'm running Daphne from supervisor on Ubuntu 18.04 with the `--unix-socket` option to bind to a Unix socket rather than a TCP host/port:

```
command=daphne --unix-socket /home/project/run/daphne.sock project.asgi:application
```

After a power failure, an instance of file `daphne.sock` was left behind, and after reboot Daphne refused to start, until I manually removed the offending file.

Is there a way to safely remove the file at system startup before supervisor is run?

I understand that this is not an issue specific to Daphne, and can affect other components like PostgreSQL, so any suggestion suitable to cleanup files before services started by either supervisor or systemd would be much appreciated

Comment: Manage it with a systemd socket unit file.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: That requires the program itself to support systemd socket integration, otherwise it just makes the same "socket already exists" problem happen 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), e.g. create the file inside `/dev/shm`.

> It is intended to appear as a mounted file system, but stored in **volatile memory** instead of a persistent storage device.

<sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

In my Debian `/run` is also `tmpfs` and I can see few tools have created their sockets there. According to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) `/run` is a good place for a socket created by a system-wide service.

> Run-time variable data: Information about the running system since last boot, e.g., currently logged-in users and running daemons. Files under this directory must be either removed or truncated at the beginning of the boot process; but this is not necessary on systems that provide this directory as a temporary filesystem (tmpfs).

In my Debian `/run` belongs to root and its mode bits (permissions) are `rwxr-xr-x`. Normal users cannot benefit from it.

On the other hand `/dev/shm` is `rwxrwxrwt`, anyone can use it. But since it's a "common land" (like `/tmp`), few problems arise. Possibility of name conflicts is one of them. Two users may disturb each other even if their intentions are perfectly harmless.

Then there is [`/run/user/$uid`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162911/108618), also as `tmpfs`:

> used for storing files used by running processes for that user. […]
>   This directory is local to the system and only accessible by the target user. So applications looking to store their files locally no longer have to worry about access control.

Comment: Really brilliant solution ! Are there any possible negative effects on "system wide" services like PostgreSQL or Redis-server ?

Comment: @MarioOrlandi In general you should mind permissions, so no stranger can access these files you create. Maybe use `mkdir -m` to create a private directory, then suit yourself in it. If your question is "are there any possible negative effects because the filesystem itself is different (exotic, unusual)?" then the answer is no. You just need to remember it's volatile.

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski, the more I think about you proposal, the more it sounds like a **superb** solution. I'm willing to mark it as the correct answer to help other people to find it, but before doing that I'ld like to experiment with it (which I'll do very soon)

Comment: Maciorowsky I like sooooo much your solution !!! but I'm facing a very strange issue in a Django project using Nginx + Gunicorn on Ubuntu18. Are you familiar with this context? I would really like to understand it, mainly for personal interest. Are you available for consultancy? and in case, how can I contact you to explain it? Not urgent ;)

Comment: @MarioOrlandi The right way to solve a new issue on Stack Exchange is to post a new question (post here on Super User, on Unix&Linux SE or on Ask Ubuntu; but please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310)). In the new question you can link to this one to provide context, nevertheless the new question should be standalone. If you suspect some particular user (like me) can help then you then leave them a polite comment and a link under their existing post to lure them to the new question. They are not obliged to respond. I don't know Django nor Nginx nor Gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I was rather asking for a paid consultancy - sorry for not expressing this more clearly. Explaining the issue would be quite an effort, and would require the setup of a VM to show it.